# Add in count of values and columns for totals

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'A': ['d','d','d','f','f','f','g','g','g','h','h','h'],
   'B': [5,5,6,7,5,6,6,7,7,6,7,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
   'S': [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2012,2013]     
    } );

df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)

S  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016
A                              
d     6     6     7     0     0
f     7     0     0     8     6
g     0     7     8     8     0
h     8     8     0     0     7
```

I want to add in the count of values that have been summed in the dataframe per year as well as two additional columns  [total of years] and [total count]

EDIT;

```
Dataframe should look something like this;
    S  2012 2012 2013 2013 2014 2014 2015  2015 Tot(sum) Tot(#)
    A                              
    d     6   x    6    x    7    x    0     x     19      x
    f     7   x    0    x    0    x    8     x     15      x
    g     0   x    7    x    8    x    8     x     23      x
    h     8   x    8    x    0    x    0     x     16      x
```

EDIT 2;

@Jezrael, if I want to select only the rows I need (as discussed in the other question), I run into problems with columns being named the same. How can we solve that?

EDIT 3;

btw, would it be possible to use a generic reference for column 2012, so I don't have to change code in the future? something like first column of dataframe; df_without_first column = df.drop(first column, axis=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) `sum` and `size`:

```
df = (df.B + df.C).groupby([df.A, df.S]).agg(['sum','size']).unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
   sum                     size                    
S 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
A                                                  
d    6    6    7    0    0    1    1    1    0    0
f    7    0    0    8    6    1    0    0    1    1
g    0    7    8    8    0    0    1    1    1    0
h    8    8    0    0    7    1    1    0    0    1
```

Then `groupby` by first level of columns and get `sum`, add level `total` to columns for `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
new_cols= list(zip(df1.columns.get_level_values(0),['total'] * len(df.columns)))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
print (df1)
    sum  size
  total total
A            
d    19     3
f    21     3
g    23     3
h    23     3
```

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames` and sort columns by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df2 = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
df2.loc['total'] = df2.sum()
print (df2)
      size                            sum                          
S     2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 total 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 total
A                                                                  
d        1    1    1    0    0     3    6    6    7    0    0    19
f        1    0    0    1    1     3    7    0    0    8    6    21
g        0    1    1    1    0     3    0    7    8    8    0    23
h        1    1    0    0    1     3    8    8    0    0    7    23
total    3    3    2    2    2    12   21   21   15   16   13    86
```

Another posible solution is [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df['D'] = df.B + df.C
print (df.pivot_table(index='A', 
                      columns='S', 
                      values='D', 
                      aggfunc=[np.sum, len], 
                      fill_value=0, 
                      margins=True, 
                      margins_name='Total'))

        sum                                len                          
S      2012  2013  2014  2015  2016 Total 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Total
A                                                                       
d       6.0   6.0   7.0   0.0   0.0  19.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   3.0
f       7.0   0.0   0.0   8.0   6.0  21.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0   3.0
g       0.0   7.0   8.0   8.0   0.0  23.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0   3.0
h       8.0   8.0   0.0   0.0   7.0  23.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0   3.0
Total  21.0  21.0  15.0  16.0  13.0  86.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  12.0
```

Also if need convert values to `int`:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='A', 
                      columns='S', 
                      values='D', 
                      aggfunc=[np.sum, len], 
                      fill_value=0, 
                      margins=True, 
                      margins_name='Total')
         .astype(int))
       sum                            len                          
S     2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Total 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 Total
A                                                                  
d        6    6    7    0    0    19    1    1    1    0    0     3
f        7    0    0    8    6    21    1    0    0    1    1     3
g        0    7    8    8    0    23    0    1    1    1    0     3
h        8    8    0    0    7    23    1    1    0    0    1     3
Total   21   21   15   16   13    86    3    3    2    2    2    12
```

---

```
df2 = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
print (df2)
  size  sum size  sum size  sum size  sum size  sum  size   sum
S 2012 2012 2013 2013 2014 2014 2015 2015 2016 2016 total total
A                                                              
d    1    6    1    6    1    7    0    0    0    0     3    19
f    1    7    0    0    0    0    1    8    1    6     3    21
g    0    0    1    7    1    8    1    8    0    0     3    23
h    1    8    1    8    0    0    0    0    1    7     3    23

df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df2)
S  2012  2012  2013  2013  2014  2014  2015  2015  2016  2016  total  total
A                                                                          
d     1     6     1     6     1     7     0     0     0     0      3     19
f     1     7     0     0     0     0     1     8     1     6      3     21
g     0     0     1     7     1     8     1     8     0     0      3     23
h     1     8     1     8     0     0     0     0     1     7      3     23
```

Comment: thanks, looks great, however could we get the sum/size next to eachother per year?

Comment: I dont understand, do you need `print (pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1))` ?  Or add last row with sums?

Comment: I add last row as sum of all values per years.

Comment: Super, give me a sec.

Comment: I have problems with column names being the same, see edit in question.

Comment: You can use `df2.columns = ['_'.join((col[0], str(col[1]))) for col in df2.columns]` instead `df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)`

Comment: can I have only i.e. join size_2012 and have 2012 (sum) stay as it was? In addition, I'll edit the question with one I had earlier regarding the first column.

Comment: So you add `df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('sum_','')` - remove `sum_`.

Comment: thanks, I only run into problems with this solution, because of the extra columns? print (df[((df[2012] < 0) | (df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > 20)) & (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)])

Comment: yes, exactly. Do you need works only with sum columns, not with size columns ?

Comment: for selecting purposes yes, only the sum columns. Both total columns later on as well, but I guess I can direct a calculation to the column names 'size_total' and 'total'? Did you see the other question as well?

Comment: Ya, it is not easy. I am working on it, but maybe the best is create new question with desired output.

Comment: which question?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. i think [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Do you have solution from comment?

Comment: If not `df_without_2012 = df2.sort_index(axis=1).loc[:, '2013':'2016']`
`print (df_without_2012)`

`print (df2[((df2['2012'] < 0) | (df_without_2012.sum(axis=1) > 20)) & (df_without_2012 > 0).all(axis=1)])`